# HTML5 display answered questions in new html page

Tags: html

I am working to achieve something like this, HTML1 page has certain questions and answers are objective type "YES or NO" , I would like to display the questions that are answered only YES to new html2 page. Basically filter out only questions answered as YES. I have the questions html done.. I am not sure how do I start doing the second HTML.

Do I have to use any jquery plugin to do it? 
Please help! Apericate your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Send your data with either Post or Get, then make a function to catch and check the value in php, only displaying what you want.